# How to prevent elements in a container from shifting around when one of them gets hidden?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So currently I have these 3 elements on the pic, and I’m using a grid to position them in a wrapper.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezl4J.png)

JSX and CSS code (`h1` is the timer, `h2` is the break time line):

```
<div className='session-wrap'>
            {props.breakSwitch && <h2 
                className={props.pauseSwitch === true ? 'timer-paused' 
                : props.breakSwitch === true ? 'timer-on-break'
                : 'timer-active'
            }>
                Break Time</h2>}
            <h1 
                className={props.pauseSwitch === true ? 'timer-paused' 
                : props.breakSwitch === true ? 'timer-on-break'
                : 'timer-active'
            }>
                {props.displayedTime}</h1>
            {props.pauseSwitch && <FontAwesomeIcon className='pause-icon' icon={faPause} size='2xl' style={{color: "#ffa257",}} />}       
        </div>
```

```
.session-wrap {
  background-color: rgb(34, 32, 39);
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 250px auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.session-wrap > h1 {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.session-wrap > h2 {
 margin: auto 0;
}

.pause-icon {
  margin: auto auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.timer-paused {
  color: #ffa257
}
```

The problem is the “break time” and the pause icon elements are able to be toggled on/off, so if one of them turns off and disappears, the timer in the middle gets shifted around as the grid row changes it’s size.

Besides grid I’ve tried `display: flex` with various settings, but still the timer shifts around when one of the elements gets hidden.

As a last resort I’ve also tried the `position: absolute;` to manually set the elements’ positions and that partially worked, but when I zoom-in and out the position of these elemts gets screwed around, which I don’t want.

What would be the “correct” or the least problematic way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

1. use min-width and min-height to maintain box sizes; or
2. rather than show/hide, keep the text and change the opacity to zero and use layers if other text must be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! I've realised i could just use `visibility: hidden` to hide elements instead of completely un-rendering them, and that keeps other elements in place. Which is close to your 2nd proposition